# Kusto Query to New Endpoint

Tags: go, single-sign-on, azure-data-explorer

I have a function that constructs a KustoQueryClient with a certain endpoint

```
func GetKustoQueryClient(cfg *config.Config, endpoint string) {
    kustoCfg := kusto.Authorization{...}
    httpClient, err := newHttpClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create kusto client with err: %s", err)
    }
    loggingClient := kusto.New(endpoint, kustoCfg, kusto.WithHttpClient(httpClient))
}
```

Since I have 2 tables in 2 DBs with different endpoints, I would like to be able to change the endpoint based on the table that the user provides. I've tried to reassign the loggingClient by calling kusto.New(...) again with the new endpoint but it returns this error

```
Op(OpServConn): Kind(KClientArgs): failed to get SPT from client credentials: parameter 'clientID' cannot be empty
```

Any ideas on how I can update the endpoint? Everything works when I initially assign the loggingClient its value but it's during the second update that it throws this error.

Comment: Why not simply keeping two clients mapped by table name?